# Only delete a certain conditional formatting rule using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

My Excel spreadsheet consists of **different** `conditional formatting`:

---

**VBA-Code:**

```
Sub Apply_Conditional_Formatting()
With Sheet1.Range("=$A$1:$C$7")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$F$1"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

---

**Conditioal Formatting Rules Manager:** 
*(Sorry for only having it available in German)*

[image]

---

Now I am looking for a `VBA` that **identifies** the second `conditional formatting` (the one that I apply with the VBA code above) and deletes it. The other `conditional formatting` should remain.

---

With the below `VBA` all `conditional formatting` rules get deleted:

```
Sub Delete_Conditional_Formatting()
sheet1.Range("$A$1:$C$7").FormatConditions.Delete
End Sub
```

What do I need to change in the code to **only delete** the second `conditional formatting`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily index into the `FormatConditions` collection and delete a specific one:

```vb
sheet1.Range("$A$1:$C$7").FormatConditions(2).Delete
```

Or if you want the *last* condition:

```vb
With Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$C$7")
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Delete
End With
```

Comment: Is there way how I can see which number (1), (2), etc. is asigned to a certain FormatCondtion?

Comment: When you add the rule, `.FormatConditions.Count` would return its number.

Comment: @Michi: You can loop over the FormatConditions from `1` to `.FormatConditons.Count`, the order will correspond to the order in the screenshotted window. To see the formulas assigned to the FormatConditions, access `.FormatConditions(i).Formula1`. Note that it will fail for FormatConditions which are not defined via a formula. So before trying to you access the `.Formula1`, you should check the type: `.FormatConditions(i).Type`.

Answer (score 1):

### Identify Format Conditions (Conditional Formatting)

- These two examples should shed a light on how to identify format conditions by their properties.

**Links** (Microsoft)

- [FormatCondition.Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition)
- [FormatConditions.Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions)

**The Code**

```
' Identified by One Property
' The following will delete all format conditions with yellow interior color,
' unless 'Exit For' is used.
Sub deleteYellow()
    Dim fc As FormatCondition
    For Each fc In Sheet1.Cells.FormatConditions
        If fc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            fc.Delete
            ' If you want to delete only the first or if there is only one
            ' format condition with yellow interior color then add:
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next fc
End Sub

' Identified by Two Properties
' The following will delete all format conditions with yellow interior color
' and with the AppliesTo address equal to "$A$1:$C$7",
' unless 'Exit For' is used.
Sub deleteYellowA1C7()
    Dim fc As FormatCondition
    For Each fc In Sheet1.Cells.FormatConditions
        If fc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And _
           fc.AppliesTo.Address = "$A$1:$C$7" Then
            fc.Delete
            ' If you want to delete only the first or if there is only one,
            ' then add:
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next fc
End Sub
```